# creating a new column that takes initial values of another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel

I am working on a cross sectional dataset. I want to create a new column, named "initial", that will contain initial values of another column. More specifically,
for each country, the column initial takes the value of another column called "ratio" for the first year for which the data is available and will take the value 0 for all remaining years.
Sample code:

```
country <- c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=5))
year <- c(1980:1984, 1980: 1984, 1980:1984, 1980:1984)
ratio <- runif(n = 20, min = 0.20, max = 0.40)
mydata <- data.frame(country, year, ratio)
mydata$ratio[[1]] <- NA
mydata$ratio[6:7] <- NA
mydata$ratio[16:18] <- NA
```

The output I want to obtain looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this in R preferably using the dplyr package?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr::first` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(initial = first(ratio[!is.na(ratio)]),
         initial = ifelse(is.na(ratio) | ratio != initial, 0, initial)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>    country  year  ratio initial
#>    <chr>   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 A        1980 NA       0    
#>  2 A        1981  0.387   0.387
#>  3 A        1982  0.257   0    
#>  4 A        1983  0.366   0    
#>  5 A        1984  0.328   0    
#>  6 B        1980 NA       0    
#>  7 B        1981 NA       0    
#>  8 B        1982  0.227   0.227
#>  9 B        1983  0.331   0    
#> 10 B        1984  0.341   0    
#> 11 C        1980  0.292   0.292
#> 12 C        1981  0.344   0    
#> 13 C        1982  0.387   0    
#> 14 C        1983  0.251   0    
#> 15 C        1984  0.292   0    
#> 16 D        1980 NA       0    
#> 17 D        1981 NA       0    
#> 18 D        1982 NA       0    
#> 19 D        1983  0.295   0.295
#> 20 D        1984  0.312   0
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)

country <- c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=5))
year <- c(1980:1984, 1980: 1984, 1980:1984, 1980:1984)
ratio <- runif(n = 20, min = 0.20, max = 0.40)
mydata <- data.frame(country, year, ratio)
mydata$ratio[[1]] <- NA
mydata$ratio[6:7] <- NA
mydata$ratio[16:18] <- NA
```

Comment: Did not know about `dplyr::first`, nice one that I will keep in mind!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ratio)) %>% 
  mutate(year_rank = rank(year)) %>% 
  mutate(initial = if_else(year_rank == 1, ratio, 0)) %>% 
  right_join(., mydata, by = c('country', 'year', 'ratio')) %>% 
  replace_na(list(initial = '0')) %>% 
  arrange(country, year) %>% 
  select(-year_rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be improved but I get your expected output:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ratio)) %>% 
  filter(year == min(year)) %>% 
  rename(initial = ratio) %>% 
  full_join(., mydata) %>% 
  mutate(initial = ifelse(is.na(initial), 0, initial)) %>% 
  arrange(country, year) %>% 
  relocate(initial, .after = last_col())
```

Output:

```
  country  year  ratio initial
   <chr>   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A        1980 NA       0    
 2 A        1981  0.341   0.341
 3 A        1982  0.330   0    
 4 A        1983  0.219   0    
 5 A        1984  0.269   0    
 6 B        1980 NA       0    
 7 B        1981 NA       0    
 8 B        1982  0.365   0.365
 9 B        1983  0.210   0    
10 B        1984  0.334   0    
11 C        1980  0.284   0.284
12 C        1981  0.251   0    
13 C        1982  0.358   0    
14 C        1983  0.288   0    
15 C        1984  0.261   0    
16 D        1980 NA       0    
17 D        1981 NA       0    
18 D        1982 NA       0    
19 D        1983  0.252   0.252
20 D        1984  0.301   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to get index of first non-NA value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(initial = replace(ratio, -match(TRUE, !is.na(ratio)), 0)) %>%
  ungroup

#  country  year  ratio initial
#   <chr>   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A        1980 NA       0    
# 2 A        1981  0.268   0.268
# 3 A        1982  0.302   0    
# 4 A        1983  0.263   0    
# 5 A        1984  0.222   0    
# 6 B        1980 NA       0    
# 7 B        1981 NA       0    
# 8 B        1982  0.397   0.397
# 9 B        1983  0.265   0    
#10 B        1984  0.249   0    
#11 C        1980  0.302   0.302
#12 C        1981  0.219   0    
#13 C        1982  0.339   0    
#14 C        1983  0.228   0    
#15 C        1984  0.393   0    
#16 D        1980 NA       0    
#17 D        1981 NA       0    
#18 D        1982 NA       0    
#19 D        1983  0.303   0.303
#20 D        1984  0.218   0
```